# How do I resolve Jest Mock error "Cannot find module"

Tags: jestjs

Jest is throwing an error stating it cannot find the module specified by path in `jest.mock()`

```
> jest


 FAIL  test/userSelect.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module '../src/actions/selectUserById' from 'test/userSelect.test.ts'


       8 | 
       9 | jest.mock('mysql');
    > 10 | jest.mock('../src/actions/selectUserById');
      11 | 
      12 | const mockSelectUserById = selectUserById as jest.MockedFunction<
      13 |   typeof selectUserById

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:306:11)
00:00
      at Object.mock (test/userSelect.test.ts:10:6)
```

The strangest part is this:
this test passes on my local machine, but it fails in the CI service we are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone else is troubleshooting a similar issue,
I finally realized the root-cause of the failing test was a difference in **case-sensitivity** of the specified path.

In my case the true filename is `src/actions/selectUserByID` (notice the uppercase letter `'D'`),
but the string I passed to `Jest.mock()` is `selectUserById`.

At some point, I renamed the file locally, which is why the test passes as expected on my machine. However, I learned a case-sensitive change to a filename is **not** detected as a change by git, which is why the CI service still had the erroneous filename.

I used [`git mv`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv) to commit the case-sensitive filename, and this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, instead of doing this:

```
const Client = require('./client');
jest.mock('Client');
```

I had to do this:

```
const Client = require('./client');
jest.mock('./client');
```

The reason why I tried the first way first is because in their example docs, they pass the axios object as a string to jest.mock, so I assumed I could pass in my own object as a string. Although in my implementation Client is exported with module.exports.